# python object taking full list

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to write my first object-oriented program.
The code I have come up with is:

```
    class Lattice:
        'Commomn base for all sublattice'
        latc = 0

        def __init__(self, conc, name, pot):
            self.atcon = atcon
            self.name =name
            self.pot=[]
            Lattice.latc += 1
    atcon=[]
    with open(inpf, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            match = re.search(reall, line)
            if match:
                if (match.group(1).strip() == "atcon"):
                    atcon.append(match.group(2).split())

print("CON    =>"+str(atcon))
print("CON[0] =>"+str(atcon[0]))
lat0=Lattice(atcon[0],pot[0],name[0])
print("lat0   =>"+str(lat0.atcon))
```

I was expecting that `lat0.atcon` will be `atcon[0]`
But the result of last 3 print statement is:

```
CON    =>[['0.5d0', '0.50d0'], ['0.98d0', '0.02d0'], ['0.98d0', '0.02d0'], ['0.98d0', '0.02d0']]
CON[0] =>['0.5d0', '0.50d0']
lat0   =>[['0.5d0', '0.50d0'], ['0.98d0', '0.02d0'], ['0.98d0', '0.02d0'], ['0.98d0', '0.02d0']]
```

I don't understand why. I am an absolute beginner and with no formal python training (learning using net and SO), so, please be patience.

**Update:**
After the accepted reply, this is the code I am currently working with. The problem with this is, I am reading everything in a `list` and then inserting those list to the `lat0` i.e.

```
    #if match found
    atcon.append(match.group(2).split())
# after getting all match, in global scope
lat0=Lattice(atcon[0],name[0],pot[0])
```

So, I think I am either wasting the `list` or the object `lat0`. Is it possible the I directly populate `lat0` when the match is found?
e.g.

```
    #if match found for <name>
    lat0=Lattice(name)
```

mini.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import re


class Lattice:
    'Commomn base for all sublattice'
    latc = 0

    def __init__(self, conc, names, pots):
        self.atcon = conc
        self.name =names
        self.pot=pots
        Lattice.latc += 1

reall='(.*)\s*=\s*(.*)'
inpf = sys.argv[1]
print(inpf)

with open(inpf, "r") as f:
    pot=[]
    name=[]
    atcon=[]
    for line in f:
        match = re.search(reall, line)
        if match:
            if (match.group(1).strip() == "atcon"):
                atcon.append(match.group(2).split())

            if (match.group(1).strip() == "pot"):
                pot.append(match.group(2).split())

            if (match.group(1).strip() == "name"):
                name.append(match.group(2).split())

lat0=Lattice(atcon[0],name[0],pot[0])
print("POT =>"+str(pot))
print("NAME =>"+str(name))
print("CON    =>"+str(atcon))
print("CON[0] =>"+str(atcon[0]))
print("lat0   =>"+str(lat0.pot))
```

**Typical Input**

```
   pot=Rh1.pot Rh2.pot Fe1a.pot Fe2a.pot 
   name=Rh-up Fe-up
   atcon=0.5d0 0.50d0 

   pot=Rh3.pot  Rh4.pot Fe3a.pot Fe4a.pot
   name=Rh-up Fe-up
   atcon=0.98d0 0.02d0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm betting that you either wrote or tested this class in IDLE. At which point I'm sure it got really confusing but the error is very simple. When you instantiate your class it's generally advisable to use the values you sent to the `__init__` and not reference other ones.

```
class Lattice:
    'Commomn base for all sublattice'
    latc = 0

    def __init__(self, conc, name, pot):
        self.atcon = conc
        self.name =name
        self.pot=pot
        Lattice.latc += 1
```

What happened is that `atcon`, `pon` and `name` were defined in the global scope and you referenced them as in the example bellow:

```
atcon=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
pot = [7,8,9]
name = ["foo", "bar"]

class globs:
    def __init__(self):
        self.atcon = atcon
        self.pot = pot
        self.name = name
```

Which gave the following output:

```
>>> g = globs()
>>> g.atcon
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> g.pot
[7, 8, 9]
>>> g.name
['foo', 'bar']
```

---

**EDIT** Answer to extended edit to original question.

I think I get it. Two things still confuse me:

- If I follow the code, it looks like you only want to get the 1st hit in the file as lat0. But you haven't explained if you only want the 1st hit in the file, or a list of objects of all hits.
- You do a split, but according to your sample input that will still return a list i.e. `["Rh1.pot", "Rh2.pot", "Fe1a.pot", "Fe2a.pot"]`, I could be presumptuous but I've added a `[0]` after the split to retrieve only the 1st hit. Remove that if I missed the point.

Here is code that will stop the loop after the first hit is found. I declare `atcon`, `pot`, and `name` as lists because `.split()` will return a list, but I don't append the results not to waste memory. I also `return Lattice` object to exit the function and avoid wasting time parsing the rest of the lines.

Additionally the final `if atcon and pot and name` is there to avoid returning in case there is a piece of text that matches, but doesn't contain all important info. In python `if` of a empty list will be `False`. You can leave the rest of the code as is (except the print statements).

```
inpf = sys.argv[1]
print(inpf)

def parse(inpf):
    atcon, pot, name = [], [], []
    reall='(.*)\s*=\s*(.*)'
    with open(inpf, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            print(line)
            if match:            
                if (match.group(1).strip() == "atcon"):
                    atcon = match.group(2).split()[0]

                if (match.group(1).strip() == "pot"):
                    pot = match.group(2).split()[0]

                if (match.group(1).strip() == "name"):
                    name = match.group(2).split()[0]

                if atcon and pot and name:
                    return Lattice(atcon, name, pot)

lat0 = parse("test.txt")
print("lat0   =>"+str(lat0.pot)+" "+str(lat0.name)+" "+str(lat0.atcon))
```

Tested on

```
atcon=0.5d0 0.50d0
atcon=0.5d0 0.50d0 
atcon=0.5d0 0.50d0 

pot=Rh1.pot Rh2.pot Fe1a.pot Fe2a.pot 
name=Rh-up Fe-up
atcon=0.5d0 0.50d0 

pot=Rh3.pot  Rh4.pot Fe3a.pot Fe4a.pot
name=Rh-up Fe-up
atcon=0.98d0 0.02d0
```

Output:

```
lat0   =>Rh1.pot Rh-up 0.5d0
```

Comment: Thanks. Its working perfectly. May I ask one more thing? As you can see, in this code, I am making list of all variable, and then adding it to the list0 (which means  possibly I am doing something wrong). In the structure of code I currently have, is it possible to add the list directly to the list0 in stead of `atcon.append(match.group(2).split())+lat0=Lattice()` for each of the `atcon`,`name` and `pot`?

Comment: @BaRud I can't work out what you're asking me, and I've had issues reading your code because it's poorly aligned by SO standards. I had to assume that the atcon isn't a part of the class Lattice. Could you edit your question providing more detailed description of data, goals, and current exact implementation because otherwise I can't see what's your question. What do you mean by list of all variables? I don't see a list0 in your code. If you need a list of objects you can just do a `[Lattice(a,b,c), Lattice(d,e,f) ....]`

Comment: I agree that the indent of the first code was bad. I have updated a  complete working code and sample input. If your time permits, kindly have a look.

Comment: @BaRud: Is this what you asked about?